# Передача POST-запроса на сервер node.js и получение ответа (Express.js framework)

Tags: node.js, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Интересует вопрос: как послать произвольный POST-запрос с помощью express.js с клиентской стороны (не форму, а какие-то произвольные данные), и как получить ответ от сервера?

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто.

```
//Подключаем middleware для того, что бы в req добавилось body
app.use(express.urlencoded());
//Обрабатываем наш запрос
app.post('/path', function (req, res, next) {
    //req.body содержит данные, переданные от клиента
    res.end('Наш ответ клиенту')
});
```

Comment: @alexandrr, спасибо, а как принять ответ от сервера?

Comment: res.end('Наш ответ клиенту').